# Removing border of QLineEdit

Tags: qt, qlineedit

I have a bunch of `QLineEdit` boxes that I want to remove the borders from. Ideally I want to just do this with one line of code, rather than having to set no border for each `QLineEdit` box. I am trying to use `QLineEdit::setFrame(false);` but this returns illegal call of non-static member function. Suggestions?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can set the style sheet for the application, or for the parent of those line edits:

```
window()->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { border: none }");
```

or

```
window()->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { qproperty-frame: false }");
```

The latter is equivalent to executing the following code:

```
for(auto ed : window()->findChildren<QLineEdit*>())
  ed->setFrame(false);
```

The `window()` refers to `QWidget * QWidget::window() const`.

Since you want to do it application-wide, you can simply set the style sheet on the application:

```
qApp->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { qproperty-frame: false }");
```

You can further use CSS selectors to override the frame on certain objects. You've got the power of CSS at your disposal.

Answer (score 4):

Use `QLineEdit::setFrame()` for that. But yes, it isn't a static method. So, you have to call it on an object : `myLineEdit->setFrame( false );`

Comment: I know but I have about 200 QLineEdits, which means I would have to go threw and do this for every one. There isn't a way to just globally do it?